# Stop Xcode UITests running for light/dark and orientation permutations

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, xctest, simulator

I'm trying to run UITests just once. However, Xcode by default seems to run every permutation of light/dark color theme and device orientation and localizations. This means all UITests run 8 times (with 2 languages). With tests that can take a couple minutes, the time adds up.

Nothing in my UITest depends on the color theme, so I'd like to turn those permutations off always. The orientation and localization variations I might want sometimes but would generally also like to turn off.

Can I disable any/all of these permutations?

Minimal reproducible example:

1. Make a new SwiftUI app project in Xcode 15.
2. Add a UI Testing Bundle target
3. Add a localization in the general app settings, then add a string catalog and at least one translation into the second language.
4. Run a UITest
5. Observe that it runs 8 times